# Magento reindex gives Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry on product category index

Tags: magento-1.9, magento2, database

We did the migration from 1.9.0.1 to 2.0.7 and when I reindex through the command line with `php bin/magento indexer:reindex` I get the following error after Product Categories Index:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '3-0-1' for key 'PRIMARY', query was: INSERT INTO `catalog_product_index_tier_price` SELECT `tp`.`entity_id`, `cg`.`customer_group_id`, `cw`.`website_id`, MIN(IF(tp.website_id = 0, ROUND(tp.value * cwd.rate, 4), tp.value)) FROM `catalog_product_entity_tier_price` AS `tp`

INNER JOIN `customer_group` AS `cg` ON tp.all_groups = 1 OR (tp.all_groups = 0 AND tp.customer_group_id = cg.customer_group_id)

INNER JOIN `store_website` AS `cw` ON tp.website_id = 0 OR tp.website_id = cw.website_id

INNER JOIN `catalog_product_index_website` AS `cwd` ON cw.website_id = cwd.website_id WHERE (cw.website_id != 0) GROUP BY `tp`.`entity_id`,

`cg`.`customer_group_id`,
`cw`.`website_id` ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `min_price` = VALUES(`min_price`)
```

What is going wrong or how to solve?

Comment: Did you get migration success message ?

Comment: @Jai yes the migration worked!

Comment: Did you migrated [1]setting or [2]data or [3]delta or ALL ? and ignore the tables which are displaying error. And let me know what data you want to migrate so i can help you for that.